# CBC mode AES encryption problem with Pycrypto

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto

I have the following code running like a charm

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
data = 'some text to encrypt'.encode("UTF-8")
data = pad(data, AES.block_size)
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
iv = encryptor.IV
decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(data)
print(ciphertext)
plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
```

But when I try to convert to a function I got an padding error. My adapted code is

```
def cbc(msg, op):
    key = b'Sixteen byte key'
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    iv = encryptor.IV
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    if op == 1:
        data = msg.encode("UTF-8")
        data = pad(data, AES.block_size)
        ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(data)
        print(ciphertext)
    else:
        plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(msg)
        print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
```

My log is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Google Drive/max/AES.py", line 48, in <module>
    cbc(b'*\xd3\xc1Y\xc2f;\xf0\xc0@\xd9E\xc5x\x11\xb4', 2)
  File "D:/Google Drive/max/AES.py", line 19, in cbc
    print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
  File "C:\Users\Evilmaax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

Error occurs in `else` statement when I try to decrypt a byte message like `*\xd3\xc1Y\xc2f;\xf0\xc0@\xd9E\xc5x\x11\xb4`. Important: This message was generated by the `if` statement of same function.

Does anyone know why this happens?
**__________________________________________________________**

**EDIT:**  Using Rob Napier's tip (thank you so much) I solved the problem. If you experiencing the same issue, this is a functional version:

```
def cbc(key, data, op):
if op == 1:
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    data = key.encrypt(data)
    print(f"Coded text: {data}")
else:
    decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    print(f'Plaintext: {unpad(decipher.decrypt(data), BLOCK_SIZE).decode("utf-8")}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating a random IV, which is good, but you then throw it away, which means you can't decrypt the data.

This line creates an encryptor with a random IV:

```
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
```

This line creates a decryptor with the same IV:

```
decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
```

That's fine in your initial code, but you don't save the IV anywhere, so when you put it in a function which you call twice, you're trying to decrypt with a different IV than you encrypted with.

You need to save the IV as part of the cipher text, and use it during decryption. If you want an example of such a format, see the [RNCryptor spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md), and if you want to see an example in Python, see [RNCryptor-python](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-python).